# How to Map One-To-Many nhibernate class mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

here is my order and orderItem classe:

```
public class Order : AggregateRootBase<OrderId>
{
    public string CustomerName { get; private set; }
    public IList<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDatetime { get; private set; }
}

public class OrderItem : ValueObjectBase
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; private set; }
    public long Goods { get; private set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; private set; }
}
```

Im using nhibernate as my orm. in mapping this code i want order to be in Orders table & orderItem to be stored in a diffrente table called OrderItems.
here is my mapping:

```
public class OrderMapping : ClassMapping<Order>
{
    public OrderMapping()
    {
        Table("Orders");
        Lazy(false);
        ComponentAsId(a => a.EntityId, a => { a.Property(x => x.DbId, x => x.Column("Id")); });

        Property(a=>a.CustomerName);            
        Property(a => a.RegisterDatetime);

        Bag(a => a.Items,
            mapper => {
                mapper.Inverse(true);
                mapper.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                mapper.Table("OrderItems");
                mapper.Key(k => k.Column(columnMapper => columnMapper.Name("OrderId")));
            },
            relation => { relation.OneToMany(); });
    }
}




public class OrderItemMapping : ClassMapping<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItemMapping()
    {
        Lazy(false);
        Id(a => a.Id);
        Table("OrderItems");

        Property(a => a.OrderId);
        Property(a => a.Number);
        Property(a => a.Goods);
        Property(a => a.UnitPrice);

    } 
}
```

also i have created tables in database but when i insert order with 3 orderItems, it inserts order but not orderitems
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you @starlight54 but my problem solved like this.
i had to change my classes a little like this:

```
public class Order : AggregateRootBase<OrderId>
{
    private readonly IList<OrderItem> _items;
    public string CustomerName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDatetime { get; private set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> Items => new ReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem>(_items);
}
public class OrderItem : ValueObjectBase
{
    private readonly long _number;
    private readonly long _goods;
    private readonly double _unitPrice;

    public long Number => _number;

    public long Goods => _goods;
    public double UnitPrice => _unitPrice;
}
```

notice that in order item you have to create fields like _number, _goods & ...
and this is the mapping of order:

```
public class OrderMapping : ClassMapping<Order>
{
    public OrderMapping()
    {
        Table("Orders");
        Lazy(false);
        ComponentAsId(a => a.EntityId, a => { a.Property(x => x.DbId, x => x.Column("Id")); });

        Property(a => a.CustomerName);
        Property(a => a.RegisterDatetime);

        IdBag(a => a.Items, map => {
            map.Access(Accessor.Field);
            map.Table("OrderItems");
            map.Key(a => a.Column("OrderId"));
            map.Id(a => {
                a.Column("Id");
                a.Generator(Generators.Identity);
            });
        }, relation => relation.Component(map => {
            map.Access(Accessor.Field);
            map.Property(a => a.Number, a => a.Access(Accessor.Field));
            map.Property(a => a.Goods, a => a.Access(Accessor.Field));
            map.Property(a => a.UnitPrice, a => a.Access(Accessor.Field));
        }));
    }
}
```

in nhibernate there is IdBag that helped me do exactly what i needed. notice than there is no need to create class mapping for orderItem class. nhibernate inserts it automatic.
but you have to create databases manually.
i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have mapped the parent `Order` as `mapper.Inverse(true);` for the `Items` `bag` which tells NHibernate that you do not want the parent to map this relation.

Since the child `OrderItem` has no mapping to the parent, then nothing is saving the relation. When you write a collection mapping, at least one side must be `inverse(false)`.

---

You have also set `mapper.Cascade(Cascade.None);`, which tells NHibernate that you do not want the parent `Order` to deal with any operations on the `Items` when they change in `Session`.

So unless you are explicitly calling `Save()` on each `Item`, then they will never be saved as it stands.

---

There is a trade off in NHibernate between free `class` layout, and optimum database performance (although very minor in this case).

If you really don't want the `OrderItem` to have an `Order` property linking back to it's parent, then you will get an additional UPDATE call to SQL whenever the parent `Order` of an `OrderItem` changes, this cost is in practice negligible if creation of `OrderItems` is less than ~10% of operations that you do with them.

In that case you can set `inverse(false)` on the `OrderMapping` to `Items`.

But my adivce would be to give `OrderItem` an `Order` field or property (you can map a private field using NHibernate!) and then give the `OrderItemMapping` a map back to the parent with `inverse(false)`, so that when children are saved, they will deal with the relation. You will have to make sure that each `OrderItem` has it's `Order` field/property filled in before save though!

You might be able to wing this by using the `OrderId` property instead of a full reference to `Order`, but you'd have to look that up.

---

As for making them save to the DB, the easiest way is to change `mapper.Cascade(Cascade.None);` to `mapper.Cascade(Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan);` (may not be exact class name). This will make sure that whenever you modify that collection on the `Order`, then `Save()`/`Update()` the `Order`, all `OrderItem`s in the `Items` collection will be updated in the DB accordingly.

You could also check out less strict `Cascade`s or save them manually as your current setup would require.

---

Lastly check out `bag` vs `set` in the Nhibernate docs, I suspect you want a `set` here, I would only use `bag` with `inverse(true)` ever. If you use an `inverse(false)` `bag` there is a performance penalty, unless the items can be identified (your `OrderItem` has an `Id`, so it can!), but if the items can be identified, then why not just make it a `set`!

The only reason you'd have an `inverse(false)` `bag` with identifiable items, is if those identifiers didn't correlate to a Primary Key in the database, that's not a situation that comes up very often (or ever in my case!).